# Bubble sort a list of integers for a number of iterations

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.x, time-limit-exceeded

I wrote a program for this problem, but it stopped because it took too much time. Any tips?

**The Problem:**
Bubble sort is the simplest algorithm for elements sorting. At each iteration we sequentially compare values of subsequent elements and swap them if necessary.

Your job is to write a program which finds a state of a given list of positive integer numbers after applying a given count of bubble sort iterations

**Input Sample:**
Each line contains a space-separated list of positive integers and ends with a number of iterations, separated by vertical line ‘|’. Example:

```
48 51 5 61 18 | 2
```

**Output Sample:**

```
5 48 18 51 61
```

**Explanation:**

Iteration 1: `48 5 51 18 61`

Iteration 2: `5 48 18 51 61`

**My code:**

```
def bubsort(num, iters):
    itered = 1
    while itered != iters + 1:
        nums = sorting(num)
        itered += 1
    print ' '.join(num)

def sorting(num):
    for i in xrange(len(num) - 1):
        challenger = int(num[i])
        opponent = int(num[i + 1])
        if challenger > opponent:
            num[i], num[i + 1] = num[i + 1], num[i]
    return num

test = raw_input()
whole = test.strip().split(' | ')
num = whole[0].split()
iters = int(whole[1])
bubsort(num, iters)
```

Answer (score 2):

Three improvements:

- Use the for loop idiom instead of a counter and use _ for variables you don't use.
- `return` the `result`, don't `print` it, you should separate processing and output.
- Use `nums`, not `num` because you should sort multiple numbers, a plural is a more sensible choice.

```
def bubsort(nums, iters):
    for _ in xrange(iters):
        nums = sorting(nums)
    return nums
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Caridorc said, move the integer casting outside your sorting function (this will also make your code a tiny bit more efficient):

```
def sorting(nums):
    for i in xrange(len(nums) - 1):
        if nums[i] > nums[i + 1]:
            nums[i], nums[i + 1] = nums[i + 1], nums[i]
    return nums
```

And later use a list comprehension to convert the strings to numbers:

```
test = raw_input()
whole = test.strip().split(' | ')
num = [int(x) for x in whole[0].split()]
iters = int(whole[1])
bubsort(num, iters)
```

It should also be noted that `.strip()` isn't really needed, since `int(" 2 ") == 2`, but it doesn't hurt to have it there, either.